# Start thread on standalone application from Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have a web application (JSP/Servlets) from which i am required to invoke a Web service to get the response. Since the web service takes around 4 to 5 minutes to send the response, application is getting freezed not allowing the user to do anything on application.

To resolve this issue, I need to delegate the web service call to an external standalone application's thread so that the web service call becomes asynchronous. With this, i have a couple of questions:

1. What is the best way to invoke a main program from a servlet with arguments. I was thinking of using Runtime object's exec() method to call .bat file. Anything better than this?
2. I want to start a thread on main program for each request. But calling main program for each request will launch JVM everytime (could be expensive resource wise). Is it possible to check if main thread is running & if so, start new thread on same main thread instead of calling main program again.

Could anyone please let me know what could be best & non-expensive way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to invoke a main program from a servlet with
>   arguments. I was thinking of using Runtime object's exec() method to
>   call .bat file. Anything better than this?

Instead of this, IMO, you create a thread class in your web application and execute the webservice call within it in parallel

Also, if you are using [Servlet3](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) API, then a new [Async support](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3) introduced by the API spec may help

Answer (score 1):

Have a Queue or better yet have a MessageBroker to submit the web service call request in your web application itself and return a unique id to the user.

Have a thread to monitor the above mentioned Queue or MessageBroker and dequeue items and spawn threads which will call the Web Service and wait for its response and then put it into a another Queue or MessageBroker or the same with a status as complete.

Provide a UI for user to enter the unique id and retrieve the results of the web service call.

This way you will not have to create Processes and can manage everything with Threads. Creating processes is time consuming and your design of creating Processes can be exploited by hackers to slow down your Server or worse crash it as well, By keep sending requests in a loop.